# Clarity Angular Vertical Timeline enum

Tags: angular, input, enums, timeline, vmware-clarity

I installed Clarity Design System and added a Timeline component

```
<clr-timeline>
  <clr-timeline-step>
    <clr-timeline-step-header>11:59 am</clr-timeline-step-header>
  </clr-timeline-step>
</clr-timeline>
```

I want to change layout to vertical on first HTML tag.
`<clr-timeline [clrLayout]="'VERTICAL'">`
But the input is an enum and I cannot give string values.

I imported in a class field

```
import { ClrTimelineLayout } from '@clr/angular/timeline';
..
orientation = ClrTimelineLayout.VERTICAL;
```

Error follows: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@clr/angular/timeline'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if you have @clr/core@next installed

Refer this to check correct installation
https://clarity.design/documentation/get-started
https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/4244

```
<clr-timeline [clrLayout]="orientation"><!--add this-->
  <clr-timeline-step>
    <clr-timeline-step-header>11:59 am</clr-timeline-step-header>
  </clr-timeline-step>
</clr-timeline>
```